# Drupal won't load properly named custom twig template

Tags: views, 8, theming

I am currently trying to override views default grid template for a front page block view but drupal seems to be refusing to use it.
I followed twig's debug suggested name, cleared the cache, etc...

[image: here is a screenshot]

I tried several suggestions, at the moment my template's name is "views-view-grid--events-front--block.html.twig" I am kinda lost, hopefully one of you guys will know what the hell is going on!

Comment: Why is there one suggestion at the top and bottom of the list? I would suspect you are being overriden by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you relying on the patch from https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2923634?

That patch is unfinished and might result in that. The length of the suggestion is not relevant, the first in the list matches, and as @Kevin said, the first entry is the same as the last.

You do not need that core patch, views template suggestions work fine in HEAD, they're just not shown in twig debug mode.